# Reference `data.table` column by name

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose there is:

```
DT = data.table(a=1, b=2, "a+b"=8)
```

and there is variable `col="a+b"` referencing the third column of `DT`

How to perform an operation on that column by reference? Let's say I want multiply `col` by `2`, so in the above example the result should be `8*2=16`, not `(1+2)*2=6`

For example, this obviously doesn't work:

```
DT[, c:=as.name(col)*2]
```

Comment: I predict that using R operators within column names in `data.table` structures will "come to a bad end". You will get code that is more difficult to understand and very buggy.

Comment: Ups, already using R operators within column names all over the place, and indeed it feels complicated and very buggy :) Well we learn by doing or listening to more experienced userRs, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `get`:

```
DT = data.table(a=1, b=2, "a+b"=8)
col = "a+b"
DT[, get(col) * 2]
# [1] 16
DT[, c := get(col) * 2]
DT
#    a b a+b  c
# 1: 1 2   8 16
```